# How to update TestrunExecutionStatus as PASS or FAIL in jira using Jira Rest Java Client (JRJC) library

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I need help to update my TestrunExecutionStatus.I am using Jira server and using JRJC library to integrate with jira. I had successfully logged in jira and able to get details in jira but not able to update or put data in jira. Is there anyone who can help me to Resolve my issue?.

I have try lots of thing but still not able to update status